# RewriteRule folder to index.php first then index.html

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to get httpd RewriteRule to redirect to index.php if this exists then index.html?

Like:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
    RewriteRule (.*) - [S=2]

    RewriteRule (.*) /index.(php|html)?q=$1 [L]
```

With priority on php (if exists), then fallback to html.

```
if index.php: 
foo.bar/test -> foo.bar/index.php?q=test
else
foo.bar/test -> foo.bar/index.html?q=test
```

Comment: I think you'd do that with an additional `RewriteCond` with `index.php` and `-f`

Comment: Can be done using the `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm` which lives in the httpd.conf file. In fact it is probably already there

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I don't use Apache much these days, does that apply to router scripts like this?

Comment: But won't there be an error when the RewriteRule has a specific file to deal with. Does this possibly just have to be / instead of /index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of the value of understanding code you copy - you already have this line, which actually does *very nearly what you want*:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -f [OR]
```

To find out what this means, we can [look up `RewriteCond` in the Apache manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). It begins:

> The RewriteCond directive defines a rule condition. One or more RewriteCond can precede a RewriteRule directive. The following rule is then only used if both the current state of the URI matches its pattern, and if these conditions are met.

So, this line defines an *additional requirement* for the following rule.

I'm going to start at the end of this rule, because it will make a bit more sense in this case. So, start with the `[OR]`, which is covered under "flags":

> 'ornext|OR' (or next condition)
> Use this to combine rule conditions with a local OR instead of the implicit AND.

So, *normally* a sequence of conditions all have to apply at once for the next rule to be run; but this changes it to "either this condition or the next one".  For the use case you're looking for, we only need one condition: "does index.php exist?" so this flag won't be relevant.

The next thing to look at is the `-f`, which is listed under the heading "You can perform various file attribute tests":

> -f
> Is regular file.
> Treats the `TestString` as a pathname and tests whether or not it exists, and is a regular file.

Great, so this condition is about what file exists, which is what we want! But what's going on with `TestString`, and what does `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1` mean? Let's go back to the beginning:

> Syntax: RewriteCond *TestString* *CondPattern* *[flags]*
> ...
> TestString is a string which can contain the following expanded constructs in addition to plain text: ...

So our "TestString" is the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1`. Looking for the parts it contains, we find:

> Server-Variables: These are variables of the form %{ NAME_OF_VARIABLE }

There isn't a detailed description of `DOCUMENT_ROOT` just here, but there is [a link to where "most are documented"](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars), which in turn takes us to [this `DocumentRoot` manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot). Long story short, it's the root of the project which your URLs are going to be relative to:

> The server appends the path from the requested URL to the *document root* to make the path to the document

This makes sense - Apache can't look for "hello-world.txt" unless it knows which directory to look in, so the condition is making that explicit.

Now back to `RewriteCond` to look up `$1`:

> $1 to $9 provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of RewriteCond conditions.

In the particular condition we were looking at, the file to look up is *dynamic*, based on the URL coming in - the condition is essentially "does *the requested file exist*. In our new condition, we don't need that - we're just saying "does index.php exist", so we can hard-code "index.php" in the rule.

---

The other part you have almost there already is the rewrite *rule*. If we take out the `(php|html)` part, which *won't* work, we can have this:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Without going into too many details, the `RewriteRule` syntax is fairly straight-forward: the first argument is a pattern to match against the URL the browser requested; the second argument is what you want it to be mapped to internally.

The only extra part that's happening here is that `$1` refers to the string that was matched, like it did in the `RewriteCond` above. In this case, we're just "capturing" the whole requested URL, so if the requested URL was `hello-world`, then `$1` is substituted with `hello-world`, and the final URL is `/index.php?q=hello-world`

---

**Coming back to the answer**, you mocked up this pseudo-code:

```
if index.php: 
foo.bar/test -> foo.bar/index.php?q=test
else
foo.bar/test -> foo.bar/index.html?q=test
```

We can reword that slightly to be closer to Apache syntax:

```
condition: if index.php exists in the document root
rule: match /test and serve /index.php?q=test
else
rule: match /test and serve /index.html?q=test
```

The only part of that we haven't just covered is the "else". There are a few ways to do that:

- We could have a negative condition ("if index.php *does not* exist")
- We could use [the `[END]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) on the first rule, to say "once you've done this, don't look any further"
- We could use [the `[S=1]` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s), which another of your existing rules already uses, to skip over just the second rule then carry on processing

Comment: wow. This was really informative. I actually haven't copied this inn, but tried to learn from a documentation that I fine quite hard to understand. I got it to work, but, as you probably understood, I dont really understand whats going on. Still not quite sure that I understand how to correctly do this, but will keep reading the documentation.

Comment: Hi again @IMSoP, I've read through this a couple of times, and also tried to follow the documentation. I'm not sure if it is a lack of understanding or just a miss-description from my place, but I cant graps the solution. The requested URI could be //domain.name/whatever, And I need to make sure that if the project has index.php, it should go to .php?q=whatever, othervise .html?q=whatever. As far as I understand your description it seems that the url are static.

Comment: @RichardHovdsveen I've [added a couple of extra bits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74265641/revisions); does that clarify anything that was confusing you?

Comment: Again, thank you for a great explanation. That was clarifying.